# debugging issue in javascript with submit button function

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, button, submit

This code seems to be doing what I want it to, until the part where the user clicks submit and a validateInput() function is supposed to either submit the form or send an error alert message.
I can't figure out what is wrong with the code.

Can anyone help?

This is the link to the actual code --
http://ciswebs.smc.edu/cis55/naruse_kevin_k/week2/default.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Week 2 cis 55</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validateText(inputField, helpText)
        {
            if (inputField.value.length == 0) 
            {
                if (helpText != null) 
                {
                    helpText.innerHTML = "please enter a value";
                }
                return false;
            }
            else 
            {
                if (helpText != null) 
                {
                    helpText.innerHTML = /*inputField.value.length + */"";
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        function validate_zip_code(inputField, helpText)
        {
            var isnumber = true; var is5chars = true;
            if (isNaN(inputField.value))
            {
                //alert("not a number");
                if (helpText != null) 
                {
                    helpText.innerHTML = /*inputField.value.length +*/ "please enter a numeric value";  
                }
                return false;
            }
            else if (inputField.value.length != 5)  
            {
                //alert("not 5 digits")
                if (helpText != null) 
                {                   
                    helpText.innerHTML = /*inputField.value.length +*/ "please enter a valid zip code with 5 digits";   
                }
                return false;   
            }
            else
            {
                if (helpText != null) 
                {
                    helpText.innerHTML = "";
                }
            //alert("passed the test");
                return true;
            }
        }
        function submit_validate(form)
        {   //alert("check everything except zip");
            if ( validateText( form["first_name"], form["first_name_help"] ) &&
                 validateText( form["last_name"], form["last_name_help"] ) &&   
                 validateText( form["street"], form["street_help"] ) &&
                 validateText( form["city"], form["city_help"] ) &&     
                 validateText( form["state"], form["state_help"] ) &&
                 validate_zip_code( form["zip"], form["zip_help"] )
            )
            {
                alert( "so far - validated everyting else next check zip code");
                // on this next if/then
                alert("yay - ready to submit now"); 
                form.submit();  


            }
            else     
            {   alert("we didn't even get to zip, smething else is wrong");
                alert("one or more fields were incorect. please correct before submitting");    
                return false;       
            }           
        }
        function submit_validate1(form)
        {   //alert("check everything except zip");
            if ( validateText( form["first_name"], form["first_name_help"] ) &&
                 validateText( form["last_name"], form["last_name_help"] ) &&   
                 validateText( form["street"], form["street_help"] ) &&
                 validateText( form["city"], form["city_help"] ) &&     
                 validateText( form["state"], form["state_help"] ) 
            )
            {
                //alert( "so far - validated everyting else next check zip code");
                // on this next if/then
                if ( validate_zip_code( form["zip"], form["zip_help"] ) )
                {   
                    form.submit();  
                    alert("yay - ready to submit now");     
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("your zip isn't valid - please correct the info and resubmit");
                }
            }
            else     
            {   alert("we didn't even get to zip, smething else is wrong");
                alert("one or more fields were incorect. please correct before submitting");            
            }           
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body
<form action="" method="post" name="address_form">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
          <label>First Name:</label>
          <input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" 
                onblur="validateText( this, document.getElementById('first_name_help') );" />
          <span id="first_name_help" class="help"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>Last Name:</label>
          <input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" 
                 onblur="validateText( this, document.getElementById( 'last_name_help' ) );">
          <span id="last_name_help" class="help"></span>

      </p>
      <p> 
          <label>Street</label>
          <input name="street" id="street" type="text" 
                onblur="validateText( this, document.getElementById( 'street_help' ) );">
          <span id="street_help" class="help"></span>
      </p>
      <p>  
          <label>City</label>
          <input name="city" id="city" type="text" 
                onblur="validateText(this, document.getElementById( 'city_help' ));">   
          <span id="city_help" class="help"></span>
      </p>
      <p>  
          <label>State</label>
          <input name="state" id="state" type="text"
                 onblur="validateText(this, document.getElementById( 'state_help' ) );">
          <span id="state_help" class="help"></span>
      </p>
      <p>
          <label>Zip</label>
          <input name="zip" type="text" 
                onblur="validate_zip_code( this, document.getElementById( 'zip_help' ) );"> 
          <span id="zip_help" class="help"></span>
      </p>
      <p>
          <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" 
                onclick="return submit_validate( this.form );">
      </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it using Developer Tools of your browser.

Comment: Move the click listener from the submit button to the form's onsubmit handler, forms can be submitted without clicking the submit button. Remove the name and id from the submit button (a form control with a name or ID of "submit" masks the form's submit method so you can't call it).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write the validation functions. You have neatly linked the error message elements with the related form control name, so use that to your advantage:

```
    function validateText(node) {
      var msgEl = document.getElementById(node.name + '_help');

      if (node.value.length == 0) {
        msgEl.innerHTML = "please enter a value";
        return false;
      }
      msgEl.innerHTML = '';
      return true;
    }

    function validate_zip_code(node) {
      var msgEl = document.getElementById(node.name + '_help');
      var value = node.value;

      if (!/^\d{5}$/.test(node.value)) {
        msgEl.innerHTML = 'ZIP code must be 5 digits';
        return false
      }
      msgEl.innerHTML = '';
      return true;
    }
```

These functions can now be called with a list of control names so you don't have to call them individually for each control, e.g.

```
validateText('first-name', 'last_name', 'street',...)
```

I'll leave that change to you. :-)

The following has minimal re-writing of the *submit_validate* function, it still needs to be tidied up:

```
    function submit_validate(form) {

      if (validateText(form["first_name"]) &&
          validateText(form["last_name"]) &&
          validateText(form["street"]) &&
          validateText(form["city"]) &&
          validateText(form["state"]) &&
          validate_zip_code(form["zip"])
        )
      {
        alert( "so far - validated everyting else next check zip code");
        // on this next if/then
        alert("yay - ready to submit now");
        return true;

      } else {
        alert("one or more fields were incorect. please correct before submitting");
        return false;
      }
    }
```

The submit listener should be on the form so that it gets called whenever the form is submitted, since forms can be submitted without clicking the submit button.

Also, having a form control with a name or ID of "submit" masks the form's submit method so you can't call it. The submit button doesn't need either a name or ID (or even a value, though you might like to give it one), so just remove them:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return submit_validate(this);">

  ...

  <p>
      <input type="submit">
  </p>
</form>
```